# example of a function space

Tags: functional-analysis

I can imagine a point $x \in R^n$ as an example of vector space with some norm (Banach space).

Can someone point me to a similar example for a function space? 
Would a trivial example be $f(x)=x$?

If so, can you also point me to a non-trivial example.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  You are saying that a point in $\mathbb R^n$ is somehow a vector space? Or did you mean something else?

Comment: If you are just asking for an example of a vector space of functions that has a natural Banach Space structure, then I'd take [$L^p$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) where the underlying vector space consists of functions $f$ for which the $L^p$ norm is finite.  But I'm really not sure that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: sorry about the clarity of the question. These concepts are too abstract and you can edit it for further clarity if needed.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.   Does the posted solution help?  Does my link to $L^p$ spaces help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I got what you meant, but here is a good way to look at it.

Given a field $\mathbb K$, a set $\Omega$ and a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $V$, one can take the set of all functions from $\Omega$ to $V$, denoted by $V^\Omega$, and define the natural operations on it: for $f,g\in V^\Omega$ and $k\in\mathbb K$, let
$$ (f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x),$$
$$(kf)(x) = kf(x),$$
where the operations on the right side are the ones on $V$.
With these operations, $V^\Omega$ becomes a $\mathbb K$-vector space.

Now, let ${\rm \bf n}$ denote the set $\{1,\cdots,n\}$.
You can look at $\mathbb R^{\rm \bf n}$ as the set of functions from ${\rm \bf n}$ to $\mathbb R$. In this way, an element of $\mathbb R^{\rm \bf n}$ is a function
$${\bf x}\colon {\rm\bf n}\to\mathbb R$$
and it is denoted by
${\bf x} = (x_1,\cdots, x_n)$,
where $x_i = {\bf x}(i)\in\mathbb R$ for every $i\in {\rm \bf n}$.

So, here is a well known example of a Banach space of functions.

---

**Edit:** A numerical example, as you asked for..
Let ${\rm\bf n} = {\rm\bf 3} = \{1,2,3\}$ and ${\bf x}\colon{\rm\bf 3}\to\mathbb R$ given by
$${\bf x}\colon\left\{\begin{array}{l}
1\mapsto 5 \\
2\mapsto \pi \\
3\mapsto 0. \end{array}\right.$$
This element of $\mathbb R^{\rm\bf 3}$ is naturally associated to the element $(5,\pi,0)\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: That was great, thanks for inferring my question. Is there a specific example  for $x(i)$ like maybe a $x_1:cos$  $x_2:exp$  ($x:R \rightarrow R$) which can make it less abstract?

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer.